# Real Word for a 'Bakebook'

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a real word that is a synonym of the fake 'bakebook'. I know that bakebook is not a real word, so I want the real word that means the same thing. I am trying to find the word that means `a cookbook exclusively for baking.`

Does a word that means this exist?

Thanks a lot in advance! All responses are greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Baking guide" ?

Comment: 'Bakebook' is a legitimate compound, and so is a 'real word'.

Comment: I don't believe there is anything as neatly succinct as "cookbook", but it's not uncommon to add a more descriptive term in front of "cookbook" to describe the specific technique or cuisine to which that book is specific.  For example, "I got that recipe out of my favorite "cookie cookbook" or "crockpot cookbook" or "baking cookbook".  If it has recipes and descriptions of recipe preparation, it's more than a baking guide, IMO.

Comment: @JEL - could you maybe please post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Dopapp, it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your word, 'bakebook', is a *real word*. It's a legitimate compound from 'bake' and 'book'; it follows the model of 'cookbook' with a greater degree of specificity; it will be readily understood and convey the meaning you intend:

> A cookbook exclusively for baking.

In English, compounding is the most common method of word formation:

> **Definition**
>   In linguistics, the process of combining two words (free morphemes) to create a new word (commonly a noun, verb, or adjective). Also called composition.
>
> Compounds are written sometimes as one word (sunglasses), sometimes as two hyphenated words (life-threatening), and sometimes as two separate words (football stadium).
>
> Compounding is the most common type of word-formation in English.

[From *Glossary of Grammatical and Rhetorical Terms* (website), "[Compounding - Definition and Examples of Compounding Words in English](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/compoundingterm.htm)", by Richard Nordquist, Grammar & Composition Expert.]

Of English compounds, noun ('bake, n. or adj.'), adjective, and verb ('to bake') plus noun ('book') are among the most common:

> **Compounding**
>   Compounding is the word formation process in which two or more lexemes combine into a single new word. Compound words may be written as one word or as two words joined with a hyphen. For example:
>     - noun-noun compound: note + book → notebook
>     - adjective-noun compound: blue + berry → blueberry
>     - verb-noun compound: work + room → workroom
>   ....

[From *Bright Hub Education* (website), "[Word Formation: Compounding, Clipping, and Blending"](http://www.brighthubeducation.com/esl-lesson-plans/59679-forming-new-words-compounds-clipping-and-blends/).]